# "Blocked loading mixed active content" in Firefox

Tags: firefox, codepen

I am getting an error in Firefox for my codepen project.

> Blocked loading mixed active content
>   “http://localhost:8888/static/components/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0”

It works fine in Chrome and Safari but in Firefox the layout seems to be wrong and I can't drag&drop objects. I checked for solutions online which mention that the use of HTTP resources might cause this error but the only external resource I'm using is this:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css">
</head>
```

Any idea what else could be wrong?

Comment: You include d3js directly from their website. This can cause this error. Use a CDN like cdnjs instead. The reason is that d3 is not delivered as Javascript file but as plain text. So Firefox complains

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem too.

Were you by chance running a local web server on port 8888 at the same time you were trying to test a project on codepen.io? And, was your local web server using the same font-awesome package as your codepen project?

In my case, I was trying to test a project deployed on our staging server on the web at the same time that I was also testing the project on my localhost.

For some reason, Firefox was giving the "mixed active content" warning about my font assets at localhost, even though I was looking at the console for our project on the web, on a completely different server and in a different browser tab.

When I shut down my localhost server, closed the tab that had it open, and refreshed the project on the web, the warnings disappeared.

I have a feeling that this might be a Firefox bug where it is mixing up font assets that have been stored in local cache and are being used across different tabs at the same time.

Comment: +1 I confirm. I just had the same scenario, also with a .woff2 file. Closing open tabs, restarting firefox and reloading the page removed the symptoms. It really looks like a Firefox bug.